# PHP: include known filename from an unknown folder

Tags: php, php-include

I am making a website the tech-tree of a game a friend is making. The tech-three itself is just a list of links going from one page to the other. The variables for each page are stored in a php file e.g.: mining.php. I don't want to have a massive list of files all in one folder. So far all I've managed to do is sort them into just the first branches of the tree with this:

```
$path = glob('tree/*/'.$page.'.php');
if ($path[0]) {
    include $path[0];
```

Ideally I want to be able to access the file from anywhere in the tree.
e.g.: The file mining.php would be at tree/strength/mining.php. And the file pickaxe.php would be at tree/strength/mining/pickaxe.php. But I would be able to include either one with the same include. What could i use to get my known filename from any folder or subfolder in the tree folder.

Comment: Please follow http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/ if you do this. It's easier to understand and will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: I worked out my own answer before I came back to check for answers. Sorry I wasted your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out an answer for myself (it took me a few hours but this will make it easier to sort through the hundred of files that i will eventually have):

```
$count = 0;
$path = 'tree/*/';
$file = glob($path.$page.'.php');
while ((strpos($file[0], $page) == false) and ($count != 10)) {
    $file = glob($path.$page.'.php');
    $path .= '*/';
    $count++;
}
if (strpos($file[0], $page) == true) {
    include $file[0];
```

Just make sure you know how many folders you have and make `(count == #)` higher.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how `include` is made to work. If you want to go on, walk the folders and check if `is_file`, then you can`include`, or better, `require_once`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)

This will allow you to not only separate your classes pathwise, but also concept-wise.

Here's an example. Say you have class `Mining` in path tree/strength/mining.php if you give that class a `namespace Tree\Strength` you instantly know where that class lives at. You can even use an autoloader to have it resolve the file and load it automatically.

Autloader example adapted from http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/examples/

```
<?php   
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {

   $base_dir = __DIR__; //Directory where your "package" lives

    $file = $base_dir . str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.php';

    // if the file exists, require it
    if (is_readable($file)) {
        require $file;
    }
});
```

Whenever you request something to do with class `\Tree\Strength\Mining` the autoloader kicks in and checks if `$base_dir/Tree/Strength/Mining.php` exists. You can have multiple autoloaders chained, however this only works for classes within a file with the same name.